# Why is nothing happening after I send a permission request body to dialogflow?

Tags: webhooks, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I want to use the Permission helper intent from dialogflow to get the users name. I have my webhook in C# that sends the following JSON request to dialogflow to do this:

https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-json/blob/master/responses/v2/ActionsOnGoogle/AskForPermission.json

```
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "systemIntent": {
        "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
        "data": {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
          "optContext": "To deliver your order",
          "permissions": [
            "NAME",
            "DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also created the following intent:

[image]

But when I send this response to Dialogflow nothing happens, in the diagnostic info it does say 'Webhook execution successful' and i see my response coming in:

[image]

I thought i would be able to say yes or no as a response and then get the data in my next response objects from dialogflow under the property `originalDetectIntentRequest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're testing it through the Dialogflow "try it now" sidebar.

Permission requests require the Actions on Google Simulator, and only work for Actions on Google. You can click on the "See how it works in the Google Assistant" link that is also on the right side-bar to go to the simulator to test it.

[image]